# arm hello world not starting - command aligned not page-aligned

Tags: linux, embedded, arm

I have create a hello world application for my armv6 ... but it is not starting

```
./hello.out
> Killed

ldd ./hello.out
> $ not a dynamic executable

/lib/ld-linux.so.3 --list ./hello.out
> ./hello.out: error while loading shared libraries: ./hello.out: ELF load command alignment not page-aligned
```

What does "command aligned not page-aligned" mean?

Comment: It is probably not a proper executable in the first place.

Comment: Post the code, the build commands, the identity of the compiler and linker, and an explanation of the environment in which you are trying to run this.

Answer (score 0):

It means one of the segments in your ELF file is not page aligned. Pages are usually aligned at 4096 (0x1000) byte boundaries.

You can check your ELF file with the readelf command, see for example the program headers for bash:

```
$ readelf -l /bin/bash

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x419b80
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
     [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000bca0c 0x00000000000bca0c  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x00000000000bcde0 0x00000000006bcde0 0x00000000006bcde0
                 0x0000000000003d1c 0x000000000000d4e8  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x00000000000bcdf8 0x00000000006bcdf8 0x00000000006bcdf8
                 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000000a8a00 0x00000000004a8a00 0x00000000004a8a00
                 0x0000000000002ea4 0x0000000000002ea4  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x00000000000bcde0 0x00000000006bcde0 0x00000000006bcde0
                 0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000220  R      1
```

The two `LOAD` sections have an alignment of `200000`. This is a proper multiple of 0x1000 (4096).